# syntax error R.id.image, id class is not exists in R.java

Tags: android

I am not able to add id class into R.java which is not exist. and it gives me syntax error;

I am trying to test the basic application which can accesses to web, download and display an image which is  as following;

```
public class DownloadActivity extends Activity{
    EditText inputUrl;
    OnClickListener getImageBtnOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Editable ed = inputUrl.getText();
            Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,ed.toString(),"image.jpg");
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
            imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);//this is for inst.
            imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        inputUrl = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.imageUrl));//this is for inst.
        inputUrl.setSingleLine();
        inputUrl.setTextSize(11);
        Button getImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getImageButton);//this too
        getImageButton.setOnClickListener(getImageBtnOnClick);

    }   

    private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: A *syntax error*, or an unresolved symbol?

Comment: If R.java is not being auto-generated there is a problem somewhere in your XML, post your main.xml file.

Comment: Post additional info in your question, not in comments; that's totally illegible.

Comment: Have you try to delete your R.Java / gen folder.

Comment: at try clean your project , secondly check auto build option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have in one of yours res/layout .xml files an `android:id="@+id/image"` you should simply Clean and Rebuild a project. If you don't have, there is a problem, just name a field as "image".

According to your main.xml, add to the layout fields:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/getImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Get Button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/someSource.png" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/imageUrl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</EditText>
```

Then you may resolve those id's from R class.

Comment: res/layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>

*
res/values
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, DownloadImageActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">DownloadImage</string>

</resources>

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me before, just remove the import you have for R.java, once you remove it, just do a project clean.

That's how I resolved it yesterday!

Comment: hi,these are my imports and no R.java;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: @CANTURK for comments like this you should edit your answer and add the output there.